# css3 child modifying parent

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to make a menu with radial shadow. Could someone please explain why the parent changes when all CSS is pointed at the child elements. I can't seem to understand whats going on.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaWBu/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mny1" class="mny" >
    <div class="m" >1</div>
    <div class="m" >2</div>
    <div class="m" >3</div>
    <div class="m" >4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mny {
    width:336px; 
    height:17px;
    position:absolute; 
    margin-left:50px; 
    margin-top:50px; 
    z-index:10;
}
.m {
    width:84px;
    height:17px;
    text-align:center;    
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
.mny > div:before,
.mny > div:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
}

.mny > div:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 150%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.mny > div:after {
    top: 100%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -50%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.mny > div:hover:before,
.mny > div:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what output are you looking for?

Comment: I want only the child element to have the shadow of :before and :after, when hovered. But it seems as the parent is getting the shadow effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are styling pseudo elements, that take the dimensions of the *first* positioned parent element. This is not the base element of the pseudo element, but the parent of it.

Just add

```
.m {
    position: relative;
}
```

and it will be ok